# If Conditional Always Runs (Hooks, React State)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

When a user clicks the thumbs up icon it calls a function that adds +1 to the number of likes. It uses a conditional that checks state to see if it has been pressed, to limit an infinite amount of presses.

If I put the thumbs up icon div in a mapping function the conditional statement breaks and the if statement always runs.

Why is that?

**This code works:**

```
import React, { useState } from 'react'

const VideoPage = () => {
  const [state, setState] = useState({
    loading: true,
    error: false,
    thumbsUp: false,
    thumbsDown: false
  })

  const thumbsUpClicked = () => {
    if (state.thumbsUp === false) {
      let thumbsUpText = document.querySelector('.videoPage-video-options-thumbsUp-text')
      thumbsUpText.innerHTML = Number(thumbsUpText.innerHTML) + 1
      setState(prevState => ({...prevState, thumbsUp: true}))
    }
    else return null
  }

  return (
    <div 
      className={`videoPage-video-options-thumbsUp`}
      onMouseDown={() => thumbsUpClicked()}>
      <svg width="20" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 512 512"><path d="M198 448h172c15.7 0 28.6-9.6 34.2-23.4l57.1-135.4c1.7-4.4 2.6-9 2.6-14v-38.6c0-21.1-17-44.6-37.8-44.6H306.9l18-81.5.6-6c0-7.9-3.2-15.1-8.3-20.3L297 64 171 191.3c-6.8 6.9-11 16.5-11 27.1v192c0 21.1 17.2 37.6 38 37.6zM48 224h64v224H48z"/>
      </svg> &nbsp; 
      <span className={`videoPage-video-options-thumbsUp-text`}>50</span>
    </div>
  )
}

export default VideoPage
```

**This code doesn't:**

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react'

const VideoPage = () => {
  const [state, setState] = useState({
    loading: true,
    error: false,
    thumbsUp: false,
    thumbsDown: false
  })

  useEffect(() => {
    someFunction()
  }, [])

  const someFunction = () => {
    const mappedThumb = [0].map(item => {
      return (
        <div 
          className={`videoPage-video-options-thumbsUp`}
          onMouseDown={() => thumbsUpClicked()}>
          <svg width="20" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 512 512"><path d="M198 448h172c15.7 0 28.6-9.6 34.2-23.4l57.1-135.4c1.7-4.4 2.6-9 2.6-14v-38.6c0-21.1-17-44.6-37.8-44.6H306.9l18-81.5.6-6c0-7.9-3.2-15.1-8.3-20.3L297 64 171 191.3c-6.8 6.9-11 16.5-11 27.1v192c0 21.1 17.2 37.6 38 37.6zM48 224h64v224H48z"/>
          </svg> &nbsp; 
          <span className={`videoPage-video-options-thumbsUp-text`}>50</span>
        </div>
      )
    })
    setState(prevState => ({...prevState, mappedThumb: mappedThumb}))
  }


  const thumbsUpClicked = () => {
    if (state.thumbsUp === false) {
      let thumbsUpText = document.querySelector('.videoPage-video-options-thumbsUp-text')
      thumbsUpText.innerHTML = Number(thumbsUpText.innerHTML) + 1
      setState(prevState => ({...prevState, thumbsUp: true}))
    }
    else return null
  }

  return (
    <div>
      <div>{state.mappedThumb}</div>
    </div>
  )
}

export default VideoPage
```

Comment: I don't understand the second example, and besides it not only being more convoluted than the first, you admit it doesn't work. First is much simpler and works. If I had to guess I'd say you are memoizing an enclosure of your state into the `someFunction` scope when the effect runs only once, so no number of clicks will change the `thumbsUp` state.

Comment: @DrewReese They're just simplified reproducible examples. My actual code is like the second example, except with a lot more going on, and actual data being mapped in. I'd like to avoid taking it out if possible, or just learning what the mistake I made was so I can avoid it in the future.

Comment: In that case then, can you share/explain a bit more about what you are mapping over and how it relates to the overall component as that seems to be part of the issue?

Comment: The issue at hand is totally reproduced with just the code above. The data mapped over are just extraneous things like views/likes/title etc. For example I set likes to 50 in the example, but in my code  it's coming from the api data. It's likely I could solve the issue in my code by simply moving everything to the bottom return statement, similar to what I have in the first reproducible example. Although this question was made moreso to see if someone could offer an in depth exaplantion of the reproducible issue, rather than a solution to fix my source code.

Comment: Just requesting a bit more context. The code in the second example, even if it reproduces something, is nonsensical. The first snippet doesn't involve mapping anything, so hopefully you can understand why one may ask for more details about the mapping part of the second snippet you say more closely resembles your code. As for the seeking of an explanation, let me refer you back to the first comment, where it seems you are enclosing your state value within the effect hook that never recomputes. Try dropping a `debugger;` or set some breakpoints and step through your code to see where it breaks.

Comment: I'm having trouble grasping your explanation. Why would useEffect need to call someFunction more than once? If the div gets put in state with the mouseDown event attached to it the first go-through, why would it need to rerun through the mapping function and be put back into state repeatedly? After the first go-through I picture the div living down in the JSX with the mouse event attached,  already--hence why you can add +1 infinitely. State does get changed, if you check state, thumbsUp gets changed to true, but it continues ignoring the if conditional.

Comment: @DrewReese And yes, I appreciate the inquiry. It's understandable since my source code for this part of the app is a bit dicy. I wrote it when I was first starting a few months ago. I did end up fixing it with a refactor though--getting rid of the mapping statement, moving it down to JSX, skipping putting it in state, etc.

Comment: Yes, but I think, *because of the effect hook*, you've enclosed a copy of `state` that never again updates. [Here](https://codesandbox.io/s/hungry-brown-rrvwb?expanddevtools=1&fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark) I've tried to create a sandbox that shows how a copy of your original state is enclosed in a copy of returned element using a copy of your `onClick` callback.

Comment: @DrewReese Ahh. Thank you for the codesandbox link, makes a lot more sense now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly if you are using any thing inside your Effects they should be specified in the dependency array. You can use this for linting https://www.npmjs.com/package/eslint-plugin-react-hooks.

After changing your code to follow those rules, it worked as you expected.

[image: Edit hooks]